# Ayuda con Fetch_Array

Tags: php, sql

Estoy practicando retornar datos de una base de datos hacia mi pagina web,con el metodo FETCH ARRAY. Me gustaria poder retornar, por ejemplo, todos los valores del campo NombresAlumnos, pero hasta ahora solo he conseguido retornar el primer valor, y cuando intento retornar el segundo me regresa el campo siguiente CorreosAlumnos...Mi código:

```
$MDB = mysqli_connect( 'localhost', 'root', '', 
'LOGIC' ) ;

$Q = mysqli_query( $MDB, "SELECT nombreAlumnos FROM 
DATES" ) ;

$a_y = mysqli_fetch_array( $Q ) ;
ECHO ($a_y[0]); //ESTO RETORNA SOLO EL PRIMER NOMBRE (Edu).
```

Yo quiero que me retorne todos los nombres del campo NombreALumnos...pero cuando aumento un número al array ( asi: $a_y[1] ) éste me retorna el siguiente campo o columna (Correos) en vez del alúmno número 2.. Y si hago esto: $a_y[0][2] me regresa cortada una letra del primer nombre,
.

Comment: Intenta con `mysqli_fetch_all`

Comment: No funciona T_T

Answer (score 0):

La [definición de **`fetch_array`**](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php) dice lo siguiente:

> Obtiene una fila de resultados como un array asociativo, numérico, o
>   ambos.

Realmente, cuando ejecutas `query` es devuelto un conjunto de resultados que debe ser leído con alguno de los métodos que existen, entre ellos `fetch_array`. Pero hay que recorrer los resultados. Si lo usas sin recorrer fila por fila te devolverá solamente la primera fila, como de hecho está ocurriendo.

Por eso, cuando esperas múltiples filas, debes abrir un bucle que recorra el conjunto de resultados e ir metiendo en un array (o imprimiendo directamente si fuera necesario) las diferentes filas.

Por ejemplo, leeremos fila por fila usando un bucle `while`:

```
$MDB = mysqli_connect( 'localhost', 'root', '', 
'LOGIC' ) ;
$Q = mysqli_query( $MDB, "SELECT nombreAlumnos FROM 
DATES" ) ;


while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($Q, MYSQLI_ASSOC);)
{
     $a_y[] = $row;
}
```

Aquí tu variable `$a_y` será un array asociativo con los datos de cada fila.

Para leerla puedes hacer algo como:

```
foreach ($a_y as $row){
    echo $row["nombreAlumnos"].PHP_EOL;
}
```

Si quisieras un array numérico, lo haces así:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($Q, MYSQLI_NUM);)
{
     $a_y[] = $row;
}
```

Y la lectura sería así:

```
foreach ($a_y as $row){
    echo $row[0].PHP_EOL;
}
```

---

#### Estilo orientado a objetos

Como última recomendación, te sugiero que pasas el estilo orientado a objetos, es mucho más claro y mucho más moderno:

```
$MDB = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "LOGIC");
$Q = $MDB->query("SELECT nombreAlumnos FROM DATES" );

while($row = $Q->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC))
{
     $a_y[] = $row;
}
```

---

También puedes usar directamente los métodos:

- [**`fetch_assoc`**](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php): cuando quieras un arreglo asociativo.
- [**`fetch_row`**](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.fetch-row.php): cuando quieras un arreglo enumerado
- [**`fetch_all`**](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php) : cuando quieres pasar directamente todos los resultados a un array. Aquí no necesitas abrir un bucle. Pero esto **no se recomienda cuando se esperan muchos resultados porque la memoria podría colapsar**. También, este método sólo funciona si tienes instalado el driver `mysqlnd` (ver documentación en el enlace).

Comment: gracias por su tiempo y ayuda..ya lo solucioné, pero la verdad la última parte me ha parecido complicada, esa donde usa el foreach..yo soy de las personas que prefiere simplificar las cosas..simplemente he imprimido la variable contenedora del fetch dentro del bucle y me ha salido perffecto, me ha retornado todos los datos de una columna: while( $a_y = mysqli_fetch_array( $Q) ) {
  echo $a_y[1] . '<br>';
}